# PHP JavaScript Clientside validation not occuring

Tags: javascript, html

I have made an XHTML1.1 Form which validates well via the PHP server. However the JavaScript validation is not working as the form is submitted to the server before JavaScript checks for errors. JavaScript code

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

        function checkall()
        {


                var Username = document.getElementById('Username').value;
                var Password = document.getElementById('Password').value;
                var Password2 = document.getElementById('Password2').value;


                var UsernameMessage = document.getElementById('UsernameMessage').value;
                var PasswordMessage = document.getElementById('PasswordMessage').value;
                var PasswordMessage2 = document.getElementById('PasswordMessage2').value;



            if (Username == "") 
        {
            UsernameMessage.innerHTML = "Choose your username";
            return false;
        }   else UsernameMessage.innerHTML = "";


            if (Password == "") 
        {
            PasswordError.innerHTML = "Enter a password";
            return false;
        }   else EmailError.innerHTML = "";


            if (Password2 == "") 
        {
            PasswordError2.innerHTML = "Confirm your password";
            return false;
        }   else EmailError.innerHTML = "";

            if (Password2 == Password) 
        {   
            EmailError.innerHTML = "";
        }   else PasswordError2.innerHTML = "Confirm your password";
            return false;

        }
            </script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="sign_up.php" method="post" onsubmit='return checkall()'> 
Username: <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username"  />  <label id='UsernameMessage'></label>
Password: <input type="text" name="Password" id="Password"  />  <label id='PasswordMessage'></label>
Confirm Password: <input type="text" name="Password2" id="Password2"  /> <label id='PasswordMessage2'></label>
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
```

Comment: What was wrong with the same question you asked 5 minutes ago? `PasswordError`, `PasswordError2` and `EmailError` are all not defined variables.

Comment: I did not know how to format questions, so the entire question did not diplay. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with your code.
You have a few variables defined:

```
var UsernameMessage = document.getElementById('UsernameMessage').value;
var PasswordMessage = document.getElementById('PasswordMessage').value;
var PasswordMessage2 = document.getElementById('PasswordMessage2').value;
```

These should be without `.value` because later on you are trying to set their `innerHTML`.
Further in your code you are trying to fill these with the wrong variables.
Also, you have `EmailError` which is not defined. Guessing it should be the same as the other elements you need to add an element and define the variable.
So all and all it should be something like:

JS:

```
function checkall() {

    var Username = document.getElementById('Username').value;
    var Password = document.getElementById('Password').value;
    var Password2 = document.getElementById('Password2').value;

    var UsernameMessage = document.getElementById('UsernameMessage');
    var PasswordMessage = document.getElementById('PasswordMessage');
    var PasswordMessage2 = document.getElementById('PasswordMessage2');
    var EmailError = document.getElementById('EmailError');

    if (Username == "") {
        UsernameMessage.innerHTML = "Choose your username";
        return false;
    } else UsernameMessage.innerHTML = "";

    if (Password == "") {
        PasswordMessage.innerHTML = "Enter a password";
        return false;
    } else EmailError.innerHTML = "";

    if (Password2 == "") {
        PasswordMessage2.innerHTML = "Confirm your password";
        return false;
    } else EmailError.innerHTML = "";

    if (Password2 == Password) {
        EmailError.innerHTML = "";
    } else {
       // The return must occur inside {}
       // Otherwise, the function will *always* return false.
        PasswordMessage2.innerHTML = "Confirm your password";
        return false;
    }

}
```

and HTML:

```
<form action="sign_up.php" method="post" onsubmit='return checkall()'>Username:
    <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" />
    <label id='UsernameMessage'></label>Password:
    <input type="text" name="Password" id="Password" />
    <label id='PasswordMessage'></label>Confirm Password:
    <input type="text" name="Password2" id="Password2" />
    <label id='PasswordMessage2'></label>
    <!-- extra HTML element for your emailerror -->
    <div id="EmailError"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I added the content of my answer into yours to make it more complete.

Comment: Ur a genius! Thank you so much. How do i get all error messages to display at once; as now they display in succession as they are in the JS.

Comment: You can add them all in an array or in a string, remove the `return false` in every check and check at the end of your whole function if you have an error message. Return false if you do.

Comment: I have followed you advice; I displayed all errors then did the tests to return false value. Many thanks